# Css3 scale animation not working

Tags: html, css, css-animations

This is the css that i have,

```
div {
    background-image: url(some url);
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-size:cover;
}

.animate {
    animation:changeSize 3s 1;
}
@keyframes changeSize {
    0% {transform: scale(1);}
    65% {transform: scale(1.2);}
    100% {transform: scale(1.4);}
}
```

And with Jquery while clicking on a button i am just toggling the class `animate` to the div. But it seems not working. I am new to css3 animations and i dont know how to debug this. Any clues would be helpful for me in this context.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FLG4D/)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi its working fine only on firefox and you has to add vendor prefix for webkit browser

```
@-webkit-keyframes
```

here it is

```
@keyframes changeSize {
    0% {transform: scale(1);}
    65% {transform: scale(1.2);}
    100% {transform: scale(1.4);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes changeSize {
    0% {transform: scale(1);}
    65% {transform: scale(1.2);}
    100% {transform: scale(1.4);}
}
```

check the fiddle
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Divz/FLG4D/17/)

and add  transition to the div you needed.

Answer (score 1):

You may play with css3 animation fill property

```
.animate {
    animation:changeSize 3s 1 forwards;
}
```

please find jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/FLG4D/16/

here I have played with "backanimate" class as well so toggle back will be smooth as well

similar question [Can't stop css animation disappearing after last key frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274230/cant-stop-css-animation-disappearing-after-last-key-frame)

Hope it helps!