# CSS animation on hover stay at last keyframe when using transform: rotate

Tags: css, animation, hover

I am trying to get this animation to stay in its last keyframe on hover but it keeps reverting back to the beginning. I don't mind if I hover off it reverts but not during the hover. I looked through a lot of stack questions and everyone said to uses the animation-fill-mode: forwards, but that doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code and a link to a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nd44uqpp/)

```
.circle:hover .spin {
  -webkit-animation-name: drop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes drop {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those of you with a similar problem, first make sure you are using `animation-fill-mode: forwards`. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274230/cant-stop-css-animation-disappearing-after-last-key-frame).

In this specific case, the following is relevant:

> [**CSS Transforms Module Level 1**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#terminology)
>
> A transformable element is an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is either a block-level or [atomic inline-level element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#x13), or whose display property computes to table-row, table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-cell, or table-caption.

Since the `.circle` element is a `span`, it is `inline` by default, therefore the property `transform: rotate()` won't have an effect on it after the animation ends. Changing the `display` of it to either `inline-block` or `block` will solve the problem.

You should also be using the [animation shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation). In addition, add in other vendor prefixes:

[**Updated Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/avatm3ts/)

```
.circle:hover .spin {
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-animation: drop 1s 1 alternate ease-out forwards;
    -moz-animation: drop 1s 1 alternate ease-out forwards;
    animation: drop 1s 1 alternate ease-out forwards;
}
```