# hover and play animation once instead of looping

Tags: html, css, animation, rotation, web

If you look at my code and run it.

```
@-webkit-keyframes circle {
    from { transform:rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform:rotate(180deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes inner-circle {
    from { transform:rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform:rotate(-180deg); }
}

#one {
    position: absolute;
    left: 500px;
    top: 200px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: #000000;
}

#two {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin: 0px auto 0;
    color:orange;
    font-size:100px;
    line-height:1;

    transform-origin:50% 200px;
}


 #one:hover > div {
     animation: circle 1s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: circle 1s linear infinite;
 }
#one:hover > div > div {
     animation: inner-circle 1s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: inner-circle 1s linear infinite;
 }
</style>
```

```
    <div id="one">
        <div id="two"><div id="three">☻</div></div>
    </div>
```

you will notice that the smile face keeps on looping the animation of rotating 180deg. I don't want this. I only want it to do the animation once every time I hover over the black circle. How do I do this?

Comment: Yes it only goes once now, but when it is done it goes back to the original position. How do I get it to stay there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want the animation to occur infinitely, remove `infinite` from the animation shorthand.

In addition, you will also need to add `forwards` in order to to [prevent the animation from resetting each time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274230/cant-stop-css-animation-disappearing-after-last-key-frame/20274314#20274314). When adding `forwards` to the animation shorthand, you are essentially changing the property [`animation-fill-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) from the default value of `none` to `forwards`.

[From MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)

> The [`animation-fill-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) CSS property specifies how a CSS animation should apply styles to its target before and after it is executing.

```
#one:hover > div {
    animation: circle 1s linear forwards;
    -webkit-animation: circle 1s linear forwards;
}
#one:hover > div > div {
    animation: inner-circle 1s linear forwards;
    -webkit-animation: inner-circle 1s linear forwards;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change all the infinite values to the amount of times you want the animation to loop. In your case it will be once so you want to change infinite to 1.